# Call a DOCKER containerized flask rest api in a pod from another containerized flask rest api in same KUBERNETES cluster

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, flask-restful

I'm working with Flask, the Docker-desktop version with enabled Kubernetes.
My goal is to :

- Create two pods
- Each pod contains one container
- Each container is a flask rest api
- Call a rest api in a container from the rest api of the other container

The problem is that I was unable to do the call inside one api, due to unreachable address. Here is the **not** working code in the **app.py** file :

```
@app.route("/testpredict", methods=["POST"])
def testpredict():
    response = requests.post(url="http://deppredict:1080/predict")
    return response.text, 200
```

I tried to make a call by the localhost, the 127.0.0.1, the `http://kubernetes_master_address/api/v1/namespaces/namespace_name/services/[https:]service_name[:port_name]/proxy` as suggested in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/)

So as a workaround, I outsourced the call, which worked but is not the correct way to do it, here are the followed steps:

```
kubectl create deployment deptestpredict --image=nameim
kubectl expose deployment deptestpredict --type=LoadBalancer --port=1081
kubectl exec -it deptestpredict-66db9b5899-f7tgj sh
  python3
  import requests
  res = requests.post('http://deppredict:1080/predict')
  res.text
```

Here is the output of **kubectl cluster-info**

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

So my question is what am I doing wrong in the **app.py**.

I am certainly missing something. Please help :D
Any insight or guidance would be greatly appreciated. **Thank you so much** in advance.

Comment: what's output when I run the command `kubectl cluster-info`. ? its just for builtin service in `kube-system` namespace as that url which. you mentioned above

Comment: Hello @Thanh Nguyen Van, I updated the post with the needed output. I'm working with the default namespace. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the call inside the web api by using the name of the kubernetes service `http://nameOfTheService:1080/predict`